# C# - Place generated QR code on Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, html, qr-code

I'm working with a C# windows form application, and I want to place a pre-generated QR code onto the form that will take the user to a certain website on the form in a 'picturebox' or something similar.
Having used a website to generate the QR code, It has given me a unique barcode image and a piece of code that looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.qrjumps.com/script/embed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 Tracker('8713921');  
</script>
```

This is HTML with reference to some JavaScript on the other side of the source link. Is it possible to include this somewhere in the code for my C# application? I have never used these particular languages together before.

If this can't be done in this type of application, is there any alternative way to get a QR code onto a C# Windows Form that will work in the same way?

Thanks in advance,

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just save the image:

[image]

Now you can just add it as an image to your WinForms Application.

```
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(@"myImagePath", true);

// Make a picturebox and add it
PictureBox1.Image = image;
```

This would be the easiest possibility.

Comment: I didn't realise it was this simple. Thank you sir!